# How to initialize WebDriver in Groovy Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, groovy, soapui

I am trying to initialize WebDriver with an instance of FireFoxDriver to do some automation.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

However, I am getting this error.

> TestCase failed [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory], time taken = 0

I am doing this script within SoapUI as a setup script, as this setup script will be use to initalize some header value. I have already dragged the selenium jar into the SoapUI/bin/ext folder and all of its lib jars.

EDIT 12/25/2015 11:41 AM PST - This is what is in Help -> System Properties

```
apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true

awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit

com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name=SoapUI

exe4j.consoleCodepage=cp0
exe4j.isInstall4j=true
exe4j.launchName=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\SoapUI-5.2.1.exe
exe4j.moduleName=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\SoapUI-5.2.1.exe
exe4j.semaphoreName=Local\c:_program_files_smartbear_soapui-5.2.1_bin_soapui-5.2.1.exe0
exe4j.tempDir=
exe4j.unextractedPosition=0

file.encoding=Cp1252
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
file.separator=\

install4j.appDir=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\
install4j.exeDir=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\
install4j.launcherId=64
install4j.swt=false

java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
java.class.path=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\.install4j\i4jruntime.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\bin\soapui-5.2.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\analytics-core-5.2.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.11.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\bcprov-jdk15-144.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\binding-2.0.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\bsh-2.0b4.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\cajo-1.142.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\commons-el-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\cssparser-0.9.16.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\cssparser-0.9.5.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\ezmorph-1.0.5.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\flex-messaging-common-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\flex-messaging-core-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\flex-messaging-opt-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\flex-messaging-proxy-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\flex-messaging-remoting-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\forms-1.0.7.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\groovy-all-2.1.7.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\gson-2.3.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\guava-14.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\guava-18.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\hermes-1.14.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\htmlunit-2.18.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\htmlunit-2.7.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\htmlunit-core-js-2.7.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\httpclient-4.1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\httpclient-4.5.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\httpclient-cache-4.1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\httpcore-4.1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\httpcore-4.4.3.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\httpcore-nio-4.1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\httpmime-4.1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\httpmime-4.5.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\i4jruntime-5.1.14.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jasper-compiler-5.5.15.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jasper-compiler-jdt-5.5.15.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jasper-runtime-5.5.15.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jaxen-1.1-beta-8.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jcifs-1.2.9.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jcommander-1.48.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jdom-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jettison-1.2.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jetty-6.1.26.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jetty-continuation-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jetty-http-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jetty-io-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jetty-jmx-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jetty-security-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jetty-servlet-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jetty-servlets-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jetty-util-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jms-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jna-4.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jna-platform-4.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\joda-time-1.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\js-1.7R2.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\json-path-0.9.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\json-smart-1.2.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jsp-api-2.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jsr173_api-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\jtidy-r872-jdk15.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\junit-4.11.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\l2fprod-common-directorychooser-7.3.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\l2fprod-common-fontchooser-7.3.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\log4j-1.2.14.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\looks-2.2.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\mail-1.4.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\maven-plugin-api-2.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\nekohtml-1.9.14.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\nekohtml-1.9.22.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\netty-3.5.7.Final.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.11.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\opensaml-2.5.1-1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\openws-1.4.2-1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client-0.31.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common-0.31.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\org.apache.oltu.oauth2.httpclient4-0.31.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\out-app-analytics-provider-5.2.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\phantomjsdriver-1.2.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\proxy-vole-20131209.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\reflections-0.9.9-RC1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\rsyntaxtextarea-2.5.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\saxon-9.1.0.8j.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\saxon-dom-9.1.0.8j.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\selenium-java-2.48.2.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\serializer-2.7.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\serializer-2.7.2.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\swingx-soapui.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\testng-6.9.6.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\websocket-api-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\websocket-client-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\websocket-common-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\ws-commons-util-1.0.2.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\wsdl4j-1.6.2-fixed.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\wss4j-1.6.16.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xalan-2.7.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xalan-2.7.2.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xbean-fixed-2.4.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xbean_xpath-2.4.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xml-apis-2.9.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xmlpublic-2.4.0.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xmlsec-1.4.5.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xmltooling-1.3.2-1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xmlunit-1.2.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xom-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\..\lib\xstream-1.3.1.jar;;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\jre\lib\plugin.jar
java.class.version=51.0
java.endorsed.dirs=c:\program files\smartbear\soapui-5.2.1\jre\lib\endorsed
java.ext.dirs=c:\program files\smartbear\soapui-5.2.1\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
java.home=c:\program files\smartbear\soapui-5.2.1\jre
java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\LINHNG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
java.library.path=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin
java.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0
java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=1.7.0_55-b13
java.security.policy=server.policy
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version=1.7
java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version=1.7
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version=24.55-b03
javafx.macosx.embedded=true
javafx.runtime.version=2.2.55-b13
javafx.version=2.2.55

line.separator=


os.arch=amd64
os.name=Windows 8
os.version=6.2

path.separator=;

proxySet=false

soapui.ext.actions=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/actions
soapui.ext.libraries=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/ext
soapui.ext.listeners=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/listeners
soapui.home=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin
soapui.properties=soapui.properties

sun.arch.data.model=64
sun.awt.enableExtraMouseButtons=true
sun.boot.class.path=c:\program files\smartbear\soapui-5.2.1\jre\lib\resources.jar;c:\program files\smartbear\soapui-5.2.1\jre\lib\rt.jar;c:\program files\smartbear\soapui-5.2.1\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;c:\program files\smartbear\soapui-5.2.1\jre\lib\jsse.jar;c:\program files\smartbear\soapui-5.2.1\jre\lib\jce.jar;c:\program files\smartbear\soapui-5.2.1\jre\lib\charsets.jar;c:\program files\smartbear\soapui-5.2.1\jre\lib\jfr.jar;c:\program files\smartbear\soapui-5.2.1\jre\classes
sun.boot.library.path=c:\program files\smartbear\soapui-5.2.1\jre\bin
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.cpu.isalist=amd64
sun.desktop=windows
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.java.command=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\SoapUI-5.2.1.exe
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
sun.os.patch.level=

user.country=US
user.dir=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin
user.home=C:\Users\Linh Nguyen
user.language=en
user.name=Linh Nguyen
user.script=
user.timezone=America/Los_Angeles
user.variant=

wsi.dir=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/wsi-te
```

st-tools

Comment: Did you "drag" Selenium's dependencies?

Comment: If you are referring to the jars located in \selenium-2.48.2\libs, then yes. Another note is that the imports themselves do not produce an error.

Comment: Yeah because it's the SSL class that selenium depends on at runtime that causes the issue

Comment: What does this mean then? Did i not drag them in properly? Is this version of Selenium not compatible with SoapUI?

Comment: You are missing a dependency of the Firefox driver somewhere

Comment: Hmm I don't see how, unless the firefox driver is somehow dependent on a specific java library that is not already included in groovy. EDIT: I see that I did not set the path for groovy. Maybe this is why?

Comment: Setting my groovy path did not work. The equivalent code works in Java but not in groovy within SoapUI

Comment: Can you please show the path from soapui->Help menu->System properties?

Comment: Updated in the main post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following snippet in Groovy Script.
Note that you need to put selenium standalone jar file in both lib and bin folders of soapui. Also, restart soapui :)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

//Initiate WebDriver
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<absolute path of chromedriver>");
log.info(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver()


//Setup Environment
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

//Your Code
Thread.sleep(10000)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Putting the selenium-java-2.48.2 into 'C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\lib' results in the same error. Same jar is also still in 'C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\ext'

Comment: This actually helped me alot! I downgraded the version of my selenium to 2.39.0 and then used google chrome driver instead and used this snippet. Just wondering why firefox didn't work and why I had to use an older version of selenium

Answer (score 0):

Download the firefox driver in any directory say, `C:\temp\browserDrivers`.
Now, edit your environment variables, add the above path to `Path` variables at the end. Make sure you separate the path with `;`. Close the environment variables.

Restart the soapUI tool.

Now try running the script, it should be able to launch firefox browser. Similarly you may do it for other browsers.